# Is this Quick Sort Logic Correct?

Tags: javascript, quicksort

I have tried to implement Quick-Sort in Javascript without any reference to psuedo Code. Is this correct implementation? if not how can i improve on it.

```js
const quickSort = (arr = []) => {
  const length = arr.length;
  if (length === 0 || length === 1) {
    return arr;
  }

  const pivot = arr[0];
  const leftArray = [];
  const rightArray = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] < pivot) {
      leftArray.push(arr[i]);
    } else {
      rightArray.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return [...quickSort(leftArray), pivot, ...quickSort(rightArray)];
};

console.log(quickSort([2, 45, 6, 7, 8, 1]));
```

I have added code of test case and executed it over 250000 times.

```
// Function to generate random array.
const generateRandomArray = n =>
  Array.from({
    length: n
  }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * n));

// Function to check whether array is sorted.
const checkSorted = (arr = []) => {
  let sorted = true;
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] < arr[i - 1]) {
      sorted = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  return sorted;
};

// Testing Quick-Sort
const testQuickSort = () => {
  for (let i = 1; true; i++) {
    const sortedArray = quickSort(generateRandomArray(Date.now() % 100000));
    const isSorted = checkSorted(sortedArray);
    if (!isSorted) {
      console.log("error");
      break;
    }
    console.log("pass", i);
  }
};

testQuickSort();
```

Comment: Have you run it through a number of tests…? Does it work…?

Comment: Yes, i have tested for 3,4 test cases and it passed all of it successfully.

Comment: Generate random arrays of random length, sort them, check if the result is sorted (pretty easy test to write). Let that run in an endless loop until it finds an array that's not sorted correctly…

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following Solution

```js
function pivot(arr, start = 0, end = arr.length - 1) {
  const swap = (arr, idx1, idx2) => {
    [arr[idx1], arr[idx2]] = [arr[idx2], arr[idx1]];
  };

  // We are assuming the pivot is always the first element
  let pivot = arr[start];
  let swapIdx = start;

  for (let i = start + 1; i <= end; i++) {
    if (pivot > arr[i]) {
      swapIdx++;
      swap(arr, swapIdx, i);
    }
  }

  // Swap the pivot from the start the swapPoint
  swap(arr, start, swapIdx);
  return swapIdx;
}


function quickSort(arr, left = 0, right = arr.length -1){
    if(left < right){
        let pivotIndex = pivot(arr, left, right) //3
        //left
        quickSort(arr,left,pivotIndex-1);
        //right
        quickSort(arr,pivotIndex+1,right);
      }
     return arr;
} 
           
console.log(quickSort([100,-3,2,4,6,9,1,2,5,3,23]));
```

Comment: The question is about whether the provided implementation is correct. Giving another implementation doesn't help much. Please consider explaining which issues the implementation in the answer has which are solved by your implementation.